# Missing help description for task based WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, rest, wcf

I'm currently hosting a few web services from within a WPF application. I also have enabled automatic help pages to simplify the service documentation. Every `OperationContract` is decorated with a `Description` attribute, containing information about the method.

However, whenever I take a look at my help pages, I realize that only methods with a return type of `void` will correctly display their `Description` attribute here. Methods returning `Task` or `Task<t>` will only say "Service at localhost:XXXXX/ServiceEndpoint".

As this pattern is used for IPC, I rely a lot on async operation contracts, so most of them will return a `Task` or `Task<t>`. Is there any way to fix this issue so the help gets displayed correctly?

[image]

```
namespace App
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMainService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "visibility")]
        [Description("Gets the main window visibility.")]
        Task<bool> GetVisibilityAsync();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "visibility", Method = "PUT")]
        [Description("Sets the main window visibility.")]
        Task SetVisibilityAsync(bool isVisible);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "menu", Method = "PUT")]
        [Description("Navigates to the main menu.")]
        void NavigateToMainMenu();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "shutdown", Method = "PUT")]
        [Description("Requests the application to shutdown.")]
        void RequestApplicationShutdown();
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service name="App.MainService" behaviorConfiguration="rpcServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="App.IMainService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" 
                  name="RpcEndpoint"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:25565/main"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rpcServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to debug with another browser (or in incognito mode).**

*Explanation*:

This is because you probably added a few descriptions, checked it on your browser. Then you added more description tags and checked it again on your browser which, instead of reloading the page, opened the one in cache. Browser will open page in browser in cache instead of reloading it when the page is static.